# triangle inequality to show metric

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

$d(x,y)= \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if } x=y \\ 
1+\frac{1}{x+y} & \mbox{if } x\neq y \end{cases} $.

Show that $(\mathbb{Z}^+,d)$ is a metric space.

I'm stuck in proving triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangle inequality is $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$. 
If any two of $x$, $y$, and $z$ are equal then the triangle inequality holds.
Suppose then that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are distinct, in which case the triangle inequality reads
$$
1 + \frac{1}{x+y} \leq 1 + \frac{1}{x+z} + 1 + \frac{1}{z+y}.
$$
Subtracting the $1$ gives
$$
\frac{1}{x+y} \leq 1 + \frac{1}{x+z} + \frac{1}{z+y},
$$
and that inequality is what we would like to prove.
I think you're overthinking it: in fact, the weaker inequality
$$
\frac{1}{x+y} \leq 1
$$
is true when $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb Z^+$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Notice that $\frac{1}{x+y}\leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Possible solution:

> ! Let $z\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, where $z\neq x$ and $z\neq y$. Using the hint, we obtain
>    \begin{align*}
>  d(x,y)=1+\frac{1}{x+y} < 2 < 2+\frac{1}{x+z}+\frac{1}{z+y}=d(x,z)+d(z,y)
>  \end{align*}